# How to enable command completion for Azure CLI in zsh?

Tags: azure, zsh, azure-cli, zsh-completion

I've found hints at there being command completion available for bash[1] for the Azure CLI (`az` command), but I have not found any indication on how to install/enable that for zsh. Anyone know how to do that, if it is possible? I use oh-my-zsh, if that is relevant.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/get-started-with-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#finding-commands

Comment: Is auto-complete feature possible for window `cmd` or even `powershell` ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is possible to have completions for `az` in zsh.

1. Get the completions for bash from the Azure CLI git repo and store this file somewhere your zsh startup script can find it: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-cli/dev/az.completion
2. Enable bash autocompletions in zsh [if it's not enabled already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249432/can-a-bash-tab-completion-script-be-used-in-zsh):

   ```sh
   autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit
   ```
3. Enable the command completions for az:

   ```sh
   source /path/to/az.completion
   ```

The code snippets from step 2 and 3 can be added to a shell startup file (`.zshrc` or similar) to make the changes permanent.

Comment: You should add both the `autoload` and `source` commands given above to your `.zshrc` file, autoload doesn't persist between sessions and must be run before the source command.  Great answer, just want to clarify.

Comment: No sure why Microsoft is not putting some effort into the official support of ZSH.

Answer (score 11):

Installed Az CLI on macOS Monterey with Homebrew I've used this commands in my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit
source /opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/az
```

Autocompletion was deployed to another location.

Comment: Path for Ubuntu: `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/etc/bash_completion.d/az`

Answer (score 10):

Also, the bash completion file should already be installed on your system.

Look for `/etc/bash_completion.d/azure-cli`

If the file is there, you can skip step 1 in accepted answer and source that file directly.

Answer (score 8):

If your OS has `/etc/bash_completion.d/azure-cli`, then with [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh) it is as simple as:

```
$ ln -s /etc/bash_completion.d/azure-cli ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/az.zsh
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

Alternatively you have to download it:

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-cli/dev/az.completion \
  -O ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/az.zsh
```

Comment: Even though the OP didn't mention oh-my-zsh, I assume most ZSH users use oh-my-zsh, which makes the answer more relevant. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In MacBook

1. Download the Bash_completion script
2. place the az bash completion script in /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
3. Make sure az script with executable permissions .
4. Update your .zshrc file as below
   autoload bashcompinit && bashcompinit
   source /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/az
5. Restart your terminal.

Comment: Thanks for providing the paths for those of use who installed via Homebrew!

Answer (score 0):

For bash here are the steps:

1: AzureJumpBox $ cd /etc/bash_completion.d/
AzureJumpBox $ ls
apport_completion  azure-cli  git-prompt  grub

2: AzureJumpBox $ source /etc/bash_completion.d/azure-cli

3: AzureJumpBox $ az aks 
You will see all the options

Answer (score 0):

I landed on this page searching for Zsh `az` completion tips. Based on the earlier posts, the following adds completion using [Antidote](https://getantidote.github.io/) for plugin management:

Add

```
Azure/azure-cli kind:clone path:az.completion
```

to your `.zsh_plugins.txt` file

In your `.zshrc`, before [`antidote load`](https://getantidote.github.io/install), add

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
autoload -U +X bashcompinit
bashcompinit
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you installed az cli with brew*, this line added in `~/.zshrc` does the trick:

```bash
[ -s "$(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/az" ] && \. "$(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/az"
```

* even if it's missing the terminal starts without errors due to the check at the beginning of the command.