# Zsh doesn't autocomplete correctly my ssh command

Tags: ssh, autocomplete, zsh

I have some problem with ssh autocompletion. 
I would like for my zsh to autcomplete on my .ssh/config file but until now it is only doing it with the /etc/hosts files. 
I've found how to not use the hosts file by adding this configuration

```
zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*' hosts off
```

But I cannot succeed in making zsh look into the .ssh/config files 
I've tried this with little hope, but it didn't work

```
zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*' config on
```

Here is my .zshrc file

```
    # If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
    #export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/Documents/workspace/flutter/bin:$PATH

    # Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
    export ZSH=/Users/thoma/.oh-my-zsh

    # Set name of the theme to load. Optionally, if you set this to "random"
    # it'll load a random theme each time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
    # See https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes
    ZSH_THEME="agnoster"

    # Set list of themes to load
    # Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random
    # cause zsh load theme from this variable instead of
    # looking in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
    # An empty array have no effect
    # ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

    # Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
    # CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

    # Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion. Case
    # sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
    # HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

    # Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
    # DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

    # Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
    # export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

    # Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
    # DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

    # Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
    # DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

    # Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
    # ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

    # Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
    # COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

    # Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
    # under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
    # much, much faster.
    # DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

    # Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
    # stamp shown in the history command output.
    # The optional three formats: "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
    # HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

    # Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
    # ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

    # Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
    # Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
    # Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
    # Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
    plugins=(
    git, 
    zsh-autosuggestions
    )
    # support bash autocompletion
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249432/i-have-a-bash-tab-completion-script-is-t
    #autoload bashcompinit
    #bashcompinit
    source ~/.bash_profile

    if [[ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/lpass ]]; then
            source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/lpass
    fi

    source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

    # User configuration

    # export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

    # You may need to manually set your language environment
    # export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

    # Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
    # if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
    #   export EDITOR='vim'
    # else
    #   export EDITOR='mvim'
    # fi

    # Compilation flags
    # export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

    # ssh
    # export SSH_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/rsa_id"

    # Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
    # plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
    # users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
    # For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
    #
    # Example aliases
    # alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
    # alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
    export PATH="/usr/local/opt/thrift@0.9/bin:$PATH"
    zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*' hosts off
    zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*' config on
```

If someone can help me on this ! I would gladly appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's the script from the [related question](https://serverfault.com/a/170481).

```sh
h=()
if [[ -r ~/.ssh/config ]]; then
  h=($h ${${${(@M)${(f)"$(cat ~/.ssh/config)"}:#Host *}#Host }:#*[*?]*})
fi
if [[ -r ~/.ssh/known_hosts ]]; then
  h=($h ${${${(f)"$(cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts{,2} || true)"}%%\ *}%%,*}) 2>/dev/null
fi
if [[ $#h -gt 0 ]]; then
  zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*' hosts $h
  zstyle ':completion:*:slogin:*' hosts $h
fi
```

Comment: thanks for that ! I had to change it to include a folder in which we store ssh aliases for all our projects. But it works perfectly !

Comment: @yaroslav-y or maybe some know if is it possible to exclude my login name and root entry from the completion?

Comment: @AskerN To exclude users: `zstyle ':completion:*:*:ssh:*' users`. This clears the existing values that were set.

Comment: @nyg thx, this is exactly what I need - now completion shows only my ssh entries

Comment: This almost works for me, but I have a a multihost line for which this solution does not work. Something like `Host host1 host2 host3` in my `config` file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75695397/rsync-completion-broken-in-zsh-with-config-file for more info on the issue

Answer (score 14):

Just in case you are looking for an autocompletion both for ssh and other ssh commands like scp, the following lines do the job:

```sh
# Highlight the current autocomplete option
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors "${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}"

# Better SSH/Rsync/SCP Autocomplete
zstyle ':completion:*:(scp|rsync):*' tag-order ' hosts:-ipaddr:ip\ address hosts:-host:host files'
zstyle ':completion:*:(ssh|scp|rsync):*:hosts-host' ignored-patterns '*(.|:)*' loopback ip6-loopback localhost ip6-localhost broadcasthost
zstyle ':completion:*:(ssh|scp|rsync):*:hosts-ipaddr' ignored-patterns '^(<->.<->.<->.<->|(|::)([[:xdigit:].]##:(#c,2))##(|%*))' '127.0.0.<->' '255.255.255.255' '::1' 'fe80::*'

# Allow for autocomplete to be case insensitive
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{[:lower:][:upper:]}={[:upper:][:lower:]}' \
  '+l:|?=** r:|?=**'

# Initialize the autocompletion
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit -i
```

This is not from me, but from a blog post here: https://codyhiar.com/blog/zsh-autocomplete-with-ssh-config-file/