# How to use autossh with google compute (`gcloud compute ssh`)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, autossh

I would like to use autossh instead of the ssh command run by google cloud while doing
`gcloud compute ssh --zone myzone --project myproject mymachine`

What is the command line to replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A replacement for the command line

Here is the two commands that allow you to use autossh:

```
gcloud compute config-ssh
autossh -M9042 mymachine.myzone.myproject
```

In my opinion, this is the easiest way to do it. The first line export the ssh key and configuration of your machines, and the second just use this alias.

---

#### More on ssh configuration

This also allow you to use the shortcut `mymachine.myzone.myproject` for scp, ssh, and all ssh related tools. Indeed, the list of your machines are exported in your `~/.ssh/config`.
This is a list of aliases you can also configure by hand.

For more information on gcloud's `config-ssh`, you can refer to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/config-ssh).

Notice that some shell environment will provide you with ssh command autocompletion, which is really helpful when it comme to remembering the name of your machines. Here is a [reference for zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309712/zsh-doesnt-autocomplete-correctly-my-ssh-command/57481405#57481405).