# Rsync completion broken in zsh with config file

Tags: ssh, autocomplete, zsh, rsync

I want to have my `ssh|scp|rsync` completion in zsh to only show me the the hosts defined in my `.ssh/config` file. I also want to avoid the autocompletion to show me any host or hostname with dots. I was almost able to achieve this with the following `.zshrc`

(just showing the relevant part of my `.zshrc`)

```
zstyle ':completion:*:(ssh|scp|rsync):*' ignored-patterns '*(.|:)*'
zstyle ':completion:*:(ssh|scp|rsync):*' hosts
zstyle ':completion:*:(ssh|scp|rsync):*' users                                                                                                        
 
autoload -Uz compinit  
compinit
```

and an example `ssh/config` file

```
Host myHost
    Hostname host.xxx.yyy.com
    User username

Host otherHost10 otherHost11 otherHost12
    Hostname %h.xxx.yyy.com
    User username
    ProxyJump myHost

Host some.host.with.dots
    User username
```

From this config file, I only want to see autocompletion for the first two entries and not the third one.

With `.zshrc` provided above, this works as expected for `ssh` and for `scp`, but the eutocompletion engine only shows local folders for `rsync`.

Any idea what is wrong?