# Using source inside ~/.zshrc does not work

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I created a a CLI tool with PicoCLI. The library generates an auto-complete script. This works fine when sourced manually, i.e.

```
source /path/to/script
```

But when I put the line into `~/.zshrc` it doesn't. No errors, just doesn't work. Tried different things like `. /path/to/script`, `source <(cat /path/to/script)`, added execution permissions, added `autoload -U +X compinit && compinit` & `autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249432/can-a-bash-tab-completion-script-be-used-in-zsh/27853970#27853970)). No success, no idea what's wrong. According to the docs it should be fine (see [here](https://picocli.info/autocomplete.html#_installing_completion_scripts_permanently_in_bashzsh)).

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your source statements. Some debugging steps to try: a) `zsh -x` - it'll dump a lot of statements, see if you can find the pico script in there. b) Add `echo` statements to `~/.zshrc` and the autocomplete script to ensure they are being invoked when you expect. c) make sure you're indeed running `zsh` (sometimes the active shell gets switched unexpectedly): https://stackoverflow.com/a/3327022/9307265

Comment: @ss1 : _doesn't work_ is a poor problem description: For sure, your file is being sourced, because you would have gotten an error message afterwards, and you can turn on tracing with `set -x` to see, what commands ar executed. You could also do a `echo $ZSH_VERSION` at the start of your .zshrc to make sure that you get the same version as in the zsh instance, where you claim that it works.

Comment: Or, your `.zshrc` file exits early, before your source command is even reached. This is why we need a [mcve] to diagnose your actual problem.

Comment: Did you find any reason? I am facing a similar issue.